# VB Script copy csv file data to excel sheet. please help me any other way

Tags: vbscript

```
Sub AddCsvDataToExcel()
'Ask User for File's Name
      filename = "E:\Surendra\Excel_Testing\NewTemplate\C_0_1\accelVsTime.csv"
      'Check for no entry
      'If filename = "" Then End
      'Get Next Available File Handle Number
      FileNum = FreeFile()
      'Open Text File For Input
      Open filename For Binary As #FileNum

      'Set The Counter to 1
      Counter = 1
      'Loop Until the End Of File Is Reached
      Do While Seek(FileNum) <= LOF(FileNum)
         'Display Importing Row Number On Status Bar
          'Store One Line Of Text From File To Variable
          Line Input #FileNum, ResultStr

          'Store Variable Data Into Active Cell
    With oExcelReadWorkSheet2
          splitValues = Split(ResultStr, ",")
          .Cells(Counter, 1) = Replace(splitValues(0), Chr(34), "")
          .Cells(Counter, 2) = Replace(splitValues(1), Chr(34), "")
          .Cells(Counter, 3) = Replace(splitValues(2), Chr(34), "")
          .Cells(Counter, 4) = Replace(splitValues(3), Chr(34), "")
        End With
          'Cells(Counter + 5, 5) = Replace(splitValues(4), Chr(34), "")
          'Cells(Counter + 5, 6) = Replace(splitValues(5), Chr(34), "")
          Counter = Counter + 1
      'Start Again At Top Of 'Do While' Statement
      Loop
      'Close The Open Text File
      Close
      'Remove Message From Status Bar
End Sub
```

Here `oExcelReadWorkSheet2` is a worksheet object where I want to copy the data.
when I run this code directly from excel it is working.
But when I save this as VBS file and running I am getting the following error:

```
compilation error: `Expected end of statement at "Open filename For Binary As #FileNum"`
```

Does anybody know how I can solve this error?

Answer (score 0):

VBA is not VBScript. Instead of VBA's Open you'll have to use the [FileSystemObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/314cz14s%28v=vs.84%29.aspx)'s .OpenTextFile, .ReadLine, and .Close methods.

Comment: Thanks a lot Ekkehard.Horner I followed your comments It worked.